# Dashed Arrow Down Rule

Tags: python, inheritance

I was reading this particular chapter of a book: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/ch04.html

On the first page there's this fragment:

> ### Dashed Arrow Down Rule
>
> If B is an instance of M, and A is a subclass of B, then A is an instance of M as well.

I'm unable to imagine this situation and I think that this rule confuses instances and classes. Is there any working code solution to achieve this kind of relationship? Or maybe I'm understanding it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look poorly worded. I think it should probably read something like:

> If B is an instance of M, and M is a subclass of A, then B is an instance of A as well.

However, if you want to take it literally, you could interpret it as

- `M` - a metaclass
- `B` - an instance of `M`, i.e., a class
- `A` - a subclass of `B`

In that case, it is indeed true that `A` is also an instance of the metaclass `M`.

Having looked at Figure 4.2 on that page, it seems clear that you can only interpret `M` as a metaclass, since `A` and `B` are clearly classes and `X` is an instance of `A`. The odd thing is that nowhere else does the author seem to acknowledge the concept of metaclasses, so presenting a rule that implies their existence is odd.

Comment: Outside of the chapter, the book states that it is talks about new style classes and metaclasses. http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html